# R Take Minimum Of Column For Each Group

Tags: r, dplyr, data-cleaning

Sample Data

```
data =data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5),
score=c(10,6,1,7,6,0,8,5,5,1),
WANT=c(6,6,1,1,0,0,5,5,1,1))
```

Objective is to make new column WANT which equals to the minimum value of score copied for each id. This is my attempt with dplyr but this only makes the data smaller and gives one single row for id.

```
library(dplyr)    
data %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    slice(which.min(score))
```

Comment: instead of ` slice(which.min(score))` use `mutate(want2 = min(score))`

Comment: @imi error: eplacement has 5 rows, data has 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no error for me:

```
data =data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5),
             score=c(10,6,1,7,6,0,8,5,5,1),
             WANT=c(6,6,1,1,0,0,5,5,1,1))


library(dplyr)    
data %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(want2 = min(score))
      id score  WANT want2
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1    10     6     6
 2     1     6     6     6
 3     2     1     1     1
 4     2     7     1     1
 5     3     6     0     0
 6     3     0     0     0
 7     4     8     5     5
 8     4     5     5     5
 9     5     5     1     1
10     5     1     1     1
```

And you can summerise it by:

```
data %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(want2 = min(score))
     id want2
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     6
2     2     1
3     3     0
4     4     5
5     5     1
```